How to fix product import error with WooCommerce
I try to upload the product CSV file from my old store to the new one.
Products > Import > (we browse the product CSV file from the computer) > Column Mapping
show this error massage
Deprecated: trim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/ourdomainname.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/import/class-wc-product-csv-importer.php on line 93

More information:
WordPress 6.7.1
PHP 8.3.14 Dedicated FPM application served by nginx
How can I fix this issue?

Is WooCommerce up-to-date?

Yes to last wersion: 9.4.2

Maybe your CSV is incorrect.

This error message is due to the fact that parameter 1 (string) passed null to the trim() function has been deprecated in PHP 8. This usually means that a variable was not properly initialized or assigned a value before it was passed to the trim() function.
To fix this, you can check if the variable is null before calling the trim() function and handle it appropriately. Example:
<?php
// Assume that $string is the variable you want to pass to trim().
if (isset($string) && !empty($string)) {
    $trimmed_string = trim($string);
} else {
    // Handling of empty or undefined cases
    $trimmed_string = '';
}
?>

This ensures that the variable is initialized and not null before it is passed to the trim() function.
If you encounter this problem when importing a CSV file, you can check the code in the import logic to make sure that all variables passed to the trim() function have been properly assigned values.
